# How to update a row in sheet using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having data in a sheet for each date. Everyday i have to update the data for each date For this i have used AppScript in which i have written a logic that will get all the dates from the sheet. and for each date, it will make an API and get the latest record.

Till the above part, it works fine. But i don't know how to update the data for the selected date in the sheet using AppScript.

```
function myFunction() {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++) {
    var date = rows[i][0];
    var formattedDate = convertToDateFormat(date);
    
    var url = "https://API_END_POINT/report?date=" + formattedDate;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  
    //Parse JSON
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    
    replaceDataInSheet(data, formattedDate, i);
  }
}
```

Function to update the sheet

```
function replaceDataInSheet(data, formattedDate, index) {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var currentRow = rows[index];

  var messageTypes = Array(23).fill(0);
  var messaageLabels = [
      "Bot Treatment",
      "Bot Followup",
      "BotUnderInvestigation",
      "BTAwaitingSolution",
      "BT Completed",   
      "Image Requested",
      "Feedback Requested",
      "Direct Treatment",
      "DT Followup",
      "DTUnderInvestigation",
      "Status Requested",
      "DT Completed",
      "Type Requested",
      "Open",
      "Case Canceled",
      "Consultation",
      "Consultation Querying",
      "Consultation Timeout",
      "Consultation Completed",
      "New Farm",
      "New Farm Querying",
      "NewFarm Timeout",
      "New Farm Completed"
  ];
  
  for(var i=0; i<data.total_no_of_cases_on_message_type.length; i++){
    if(messaageLabels.includes(data.total_no_of_cases_on_message_type[i].message_type)) {
      var messageType = data.total_no_of_cases_on_message_type[i].message_type;
      var messageCount = data.total_no_of_cases_on_message_type[i].count;
      
      messageTypes[messaageLabels.indexOf(messageType)] = messageCount;
    }
  }
  
  var values = [
    formattedDate,
    data.total_no_of_users,
    data.total_no_of_cases,
    messageTypes[0],
    messageTypes[1],
    messageTypes[2],
    messageTypes[3],
    messageTypes[4],
    messageTypes[5],
    messageTypes[6],
    messageTypes[7],
    messageTypes[8],
    messageTypes[9],
    messageTypes[10],
    messageTypes[11],
    messageTypes[12],
    messageTypes[13],
    messageTypes[14],
    messageTypes[15],
    messageTypes[16],
    messageTypes[17],
    messageTypes[18],
    messageTypes[19],
    messageTypes[20],
    messageTypes[21],
    messageTypes[22],
    data.total_no_of_users_made_payment
  ]
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, index).setValues(values);
}
```

```
function convertToDateFormat(date) {
  return formattedDate = [
      date.getFullYear(),
      ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
      ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
    ].join('-');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) to get the spreadsheet values as strings formatted in the same way as shown. Then you can avoid the `convertToDateFormat()` step entirely.
2. When using `setValues()`, you need to first define a range that has the exact same dimensions as the new values.
3. No need to retype `messageTypes[n]` in your final `values` array. You already have it ordered, so you're leaving yourself open to errors. In my approach below, I've used the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new array.

```
/**
 * For each date in the table, get the API data and update the corresponding row.
 */
function update() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var table = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  
  for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < table.length; rowIndex++) {
    var row = table[rowIndex];
    var rowDate = row[0];
    var data = getApiData(rowDate);
    var updatedRowValues = generateRowValues(data, rowDate);
    sheet.getRange(
      rowIndex+1, // Ranges are 1-indexed
      1, // Column A
      1, // Only changing one row (e.g. height)
      updatedRowValues.length // Number of columns (e.g. width)
    ).setValues([updatedRowValues]);
  }
}

/**
 * Get data from the API for the specified date.
 * @param {string} dateString - YYYY-MM-DD
 * @returns {object}
 */
function getApiData(dateString) {
  var url = "https://API_END_POINT/report?date=" + dateString;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  
  //Parse JSON
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);
}

/**
 * Generate the row values from the API data for a given date.
 * @param {object} data - The API data.
 * @param {string} dateString - YYYY-MM-DD
 * @returns {object[]}
 */
function generateRowValues(data, dateString) {  
  var messageLabels = [
    "Bot Treatment",
    "Bot Followup",
    "BotUnderInvestigation",
    "BTAwaitingSolution",
    "BT Completed",   
    "Image Requested",
    "Feedback Requested",
    "Direct Treatment",
    "DT Followup",
    "DTUnderInvestigation",
    "Status Requested",
    "DT Completed",
    "Type Requested",
    "Open",
    "Case Canceled",
    "Consultation",
    "Consultation Querying",
    "Consultation Timeout",
    "Consultation Completed",
    "New Farm",
    "New Farm Querying",
    "NewFarm Timeout",
    "New Farm Completed"
  ];
  var messageTypes = Array(messageLabels.length).fill(0);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.total_no_of_cases_on_message_type.length; i++) {
    var messageTypeCases = data.total_no_of_cases_on_message_type[i];
    if (messageLabels.includes(messageTypeCases.message_type)) {
      messageTypes[messageLabels.indexOf(messageTypeCases.message_type)] = messageTypeCases.count;
    }
  }
  
  return [
    dateString,
    data.total_no_of_users,
    data.total_no_of_cases,
    ...messageTypes,
    data.total_no_of_users_made_payment
  ];
}
```

I hope that works. If so, then please consider modifying it to use [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)–instead of calling `setValues()` multiple times, it may make sense to call it only once for the entire sheet. Similarly, you may be able to make all of your API requests in one call using [`UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)).